# How do I use a for loop to add new entries to a python dictionary?

Tags: python, loops, dictionary, for-loop

I am trying to make a for loop which adds new entries to my dictionary which should be in the format of {1:0.5, 2:0.5, 3:0.5....}

I need to make it do this 200 times. But for some reason my code prints out an empty dictionary:

```
initial_dict = {}

for i in initial_dict.copy():
    if len(i) < 200:
        initial_dict.update({i: 0.5})


print initial_dict
```

Any ideas?

Comment: you're iterating over an empty dictionary

Comment: That is going to give you an error. Also, it's very unclear what you're trying to do. For example, the for-loop will never be entered with the current configuration of `initial_dict`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
>>> d = {}
>>> for i in range(1, 201):
...     d[i] = 0.5
... 
>>> d
```

or the shorter form using [dict comprehensions](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/):

```
>>> { i: 0.5 for i in range(1, 201) }
```

Comment: Thanks, this was a lot of help :)

Comment: Or, the short form in python2.6 or prior:  `dict((i,0.5) for i in xrange(1,201))`

Answer (score 1):

Use a dict comprehension:

```
initial_dict = {i:0.5 for i in range(1, 201)}
```

Comment: This generates a range from 0 to 199. Edit: Fixed.

Comment: @Fabian: Since the condition in his script was `< 200`, I assumed that that's what he wanted. You're probably right, though.

Answer (score 1):

use `dict.fromkeys()`:

help on `dict.fromkeys()`:

> dict.fromkeys(S[,v]) -> New dict with keys from S and values equal to
>   v. v defaults to None.

```
dic=dict.fromkeys(range(1,201),0.5)
```

example:

```
In [11]: dic=dict.fromkeys(range(1,10),0.5)

In [12]: dic
Out[12]: {1: 0.5, 2: 0.5, 3: 0.5, 4: 0.5, 5: 0.5, 6: 0.5, 7: 0.5, 8: 0.5, 9: 0.5}
```

`dict.fromkeys()` is also more efficient than the `dict comprehension`:

```
In [17]: %timeit { i: 0.5 for i in range(1, 201) }
10000 loops, best of 3: 35.8 us per loop

In [18]: %timeit dict.fromkeys(range(1,201),0.5)
10000 loops, best of 3: 21.6 us per loop
```

Answer (score 1):

```
In [1]: dict.fromkeys(range(10), 0.5)
Out[1]: 
{0: 0.5,
 1: 0.5,
 2: 0.5,
 3: 0.5,
 4: 0.5,
 5: 0.5,
 6: 0.5,
 7: 0.5,
 8: 0.5,
 9: 0.5}
```

It's unclear whether you are constructing a new dictionary like this, or need to update an existing one with these keys/values. If the latter, just write:

```
initial_dict.update(dict.fromkeys(range(200), 0.5))
```

Comment: Some people just downvote for no reason :(, a +1 for correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

`initial_dict` is empty, so I don't understand how you expect to iterate through a copy of it. That loop will never even enter.

If you just want to create a dictionary with keys 1 to 200, you could do this:

```
dict.fromkeys(xrange(1,201), 0.5)
```

Answer (score 1):

You may write like:

```
initial_dict = {}
for i in range(1, 200): 
  initial_dict .setdefault(i, 0.5)
```

Partial snap short of output:

```
>>> initial_dict
{1: 0.5, 2: 0.5, 3: 0.5, 4: 0.5, 5: 0.5, 6: 0.5, 7: 0.5, 8: 0.5, 9: 0.5,
```

Second way (better):

```
>>> for i in range(1, 200):
...     initial_dict[i] = 0.5
```

Comment: interesting solution, can be useful if he'll need to put some other values

Comment: `Why someone mark my answer -1 its working correctly!` I have checked

Comment: I think setdefault is not require here as it is actually ,`D.setdefault(k[,d]) -> D.get(k,d), also set D[k]=d if k not in D`. So there's no requirement of `setdefault`.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary : Thanks Ashwini :) I understood your point. and Improved my answer too. I am also a new python learner.-Thanks dear

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary : would you like to remove your -1 I have improve my answer

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan What makes you think I gave you a -1? Actually I never downvote. My downvote counter will remain 85 forever. But I can give you a +1 though for a correct answer.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary What do you do?

Answer (score 0):

For python 2.7 or 3.x instead of loop you can make it in one line:

```
dct = {x: 0.5 for x in range(1, 201)}
```

Comment: >= python 2.7, don't forget that

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way to do this:

```
my_dict = {}
for i in range(1, 201): # second argument is exclusive
   my_dict[i] = 0.5
```